# What is reliability? How it is related to correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation, r-squared, validity-coefficient

We can compute real or population correlation(rho) by square-root of 1 minus R-squared.Is this a correct interpretation? Does population correlation mean a real correlation measured as square-root of 1 - R_squared? Here, Reliability seems to reflect extent of correlated-ness among variables/items (measuring a construct).Does it mean moderator effects/interaction-effects are eliminated by the this procedure to reach at true correlation?

Comment: Could you please give the definition of reliability you mean?

Comment: thanks for comment

Comment: So could you please give me definition of reliability that you mean?

Comment: There are several methods for ascertaining reliability e.g. split-half reliability. Please search and read the Net.

Comment: I do not expect “search the net for the details of my question” to be a winning strategy for getting people to consult for free. You might want to consider fleshing out your question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have had such intention to win or lose.